# Scraping href using beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href, findall

I want to fetch particular href of a webpage when I use find_all I get all the href present in that website I just need some section of it using beautifulsoup python.How can I do that

https://fitaliancook.com I want the href of only recipes I tried it using soup.find_all

Answer (score 0):

```
posts = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "entry-featured-image-url"})
for a in posts:
    print("Found the URL:", a['href'])
```